# Unit testing for asyncio coroutines

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-asyncio

I'd like to use `nosetests` to test the coroutines in a class. My first thought was to call each coroutine with `asyncio.run()`. Unfortunately, I started to receive runtime exceptions after the first test. This is a minimal example to show the problem:

```
import asyncio

class MyClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.event = asyncio.Event()

    async def hello(self):
        print("Hello from MyClass")

class TestMyClass:

    def setup(self):
        self.my_class = MyClass()

    def test1(self):
        asyncio.run(self.my_class.hello())

    def test2(self):
        asyncio.run(self.my_class.hello())
```

When this script is run with `nosetests`, a `RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'MainThread'.` is raised for `test2`. The offending line is the creation of an `Event` in `MyClass`. I don't fully understand the issue. The [documentation for `asyncio.run()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run) states that the function "should be used as a main entry point for asyncio programs, and should ideally only be called once." To me, this sounds as if it's possible to call `asyncio.run()` multiple times in a program, even though it's not recommended.

Anyway, as the error points to a non-existing event loop, I decided to manage the event loop manually, and came up with the following workaround:

```
import asyncio

class MyClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.event = asyncio.Event()

    async def hello(self):
        print("Hello from MyClass")

class TestMyClass:

    def __init__(self):
        try:
            self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        except RuntimeError:
            self.loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()

    def setup(self):
        asyncio.set_event_loop(self.loop)
        self.my_class = MyClass()

    def test1(self):
        asyncio.run(self.my_class.hello())

    def test2(self):
        asyncio.run(self.my_class.hello())
```

The `try...except` in the initialization is required when multiple test scripts are run sequentially. I'm using Python 3.7.6.

My workaround doesn't look very clean to me, and I'm wondering if there's a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

A potential cleaner workaround, since I'm using `asyncio` low-level APIs anyway, could be this:

```
import asyncio

class MyClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.event = asyncio.Event()

    async def hello(self):
        print("Hello from MyClass")

class TestMyClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    def setup(self):
        self.my_class = MyClass()

    def test1(self):
        self.loop.run_until_complete(self.my_class.hello())

    def test2(self):
        self.loop.run_until_complete(self.my_class.hello())
```

Is there any possible issues with this approach?